# networkx, undirected graph: for one source node, find directly connected neighbors from target nodes list

Tags: graph, routes, graph-theory, networkx

In an undirected graph, for a given source node ('sa' in code / pic below) and a list of target nodes (tlist=['ta','tb','tc','td','te','tf']) I am trying to find the subset of directly connected target nodes, i.e. if they are connected via another target node, they are not going into the subset.

So for undirected graph G:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()   
G.add_path(['te','og','oe','sa','oa','ta','tb'])
#G = nx.Graph()   
G.add_path(['tf','oe'])
G.add_path(['sa','of','td','od'])
G.add_path(['sa','ob','tc','oc','td'])
val_map = {'sa': 1.0,
           'ta': 0.5714285714285714,
           'tb': 0.5714285714285714,
           'tc': 0.5714285714285714,
           'td': 0.5714285714285714,
           'te': 0.5714285714285714,
           'tf': 0.5714285714285714
           }
values = [val_map.get(node, 0.25) for node in G.nodes()]
nx.draw(G, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), node_color=values,with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

the resulting subset of target nodes should be ['ta','tc','td','te','tf']

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Graph Pic here https://aplikate.sirius.uberspace.de/oc/public.php?service=files&t=89614301248dab62dc77de4fc43962c7

Comment: is this an undirected graph? the simplest way would be to grab the paths from the source to each target, and verify that there no other target nodes on the path (except the last one).

Comment: hi Corley yes an undirected graph. Your proposal solves the problem, but could be to costly in a huge graph.

Answer (score 0):

ok sorry for my bad programming style, but this is only a draft. Anyhow it seems to work, please test on other undirected graphs and improve if necessary:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_path(['te','og','oe','sa','oa','ta','tb'])
G.add_path(['tf','oe'])
G.add_path(['sa','of','td','od'])
G.add_path(['sa','ob','tc','oc','td'])

tlist=['ta','tb','tc','td','te','tf']

def deduplicate_list(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [ x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

def nearest_connected_neighbors(graph,sourcenode,targetnodes):
    templist=[]
    endendlist=[]
    searchlist=[]
    tlist=targetnodes
    G=graph
    nlist=G.neighbors(sourcenode)
    donelist=[sourcenode]
    while len(nlist)>0:
        for n in nlist:
            donelist.append(n)
            if n in tlist:
                endendlist.append(n)
                endendlist=deduplicate_list(endendlist)
        searchlist = list(set(nlist) - set(endendlist))
        for n in searchlist:
            templist.extend(G.neighbors(n))
            templist=deduplicate_list(templist)
        nlist=[]
        nlist=list(set(templist) - set(donelist))   
    return endendlist

print nearest_connected_neighbors(G,'sa',tlist)
```